# Error `No gradients provided` for network returning the array of integers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to train a neural network. As input, I have an array with shape (1500,4), where three columns are numbers from 0 to 1, and the last column is binary, my training data consists of 100 arrays like this. Example:

```
[[0.74 0.45 0.42 0.  ]
 [0.38 0.99 0.78 0.  ]
 [0.74 0.98 0.8  0.  ]
 ...
 [0.87 0.89 0.3  1.  ]
 [0.69 0.87 0.54 0.  ]
 [0.57 0.4  0.83 0.  ]]
```

As a result, I need an array with a shape (350), numbers are integers and they are pretty big (indexes of an array). Here is the true answer for training input:

```
[ 669 2027 3803 7599 3795 9984 3161 5326 2063 9669 8034 1663 7386 6312
 8267 1576 9387 5557  351 5656  109 3649 6124 7635 2737 4920 6764 6304
 9471 2421 2107 9089 9857 ...
```

So ideally my network should produce the same numbers, order is not important.
Here is my network:

```py
network = models.Sequential()

network.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1500,4)))
network.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
network.add(layers.Dense(350, activation='linear'))
network.add(layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.cast(tf.round(x * data_size), tf.int64)))

network.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
network.fit(inputs, answers, epochs=5)
```

I've tried to use both the default `mean_squared_error` and my custom error function that counts a number of intersections in two arrays:

```py
def score_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.expand_dims(y_true, axis=0)
    y_pred = tf.expand_dims(y_pred, axis=0)
    return tf.shape(y_true)[1] - tf.shape(tf.sets.intersection(y_true, y_pred))[1]
```

Both variants don't work. Error `No gradients provided for any variable`. What can i do about it?

Comment: okay, how i can fix this?
network should return array of integers

Comment: You need to completely change your formulation, you should be doing classification, this goes much beyond what we can do here, this is not an actual programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using array indices as target values for a neural network output. For this kind of neural network (looks like you are trying to train a simple classifier), you need to use one-hot encoding :

If the array you are indexing over has 10000 elements, you need to replace your integer output with a 10000 dimension vector output. The target for this 10000 dimension output will be a vector of all zeros, except for the dimension corresponding to the target indice, where you will have a 1.

You can probably look into using [the `CategoryEncoding` layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/categorical/category_encoding/). You can also check out the [image classification tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/) which will help you get started

Comment: Thanks. How I can explicitly set that only 350 elements can have value 1? I need exactly 350, not 349 or 351. (custom error function with very strict punishment for not 350 1's?)
Alternatively, I thought about outputting float value and then just picking the highest 350. But it looks like it will be very slow so I am unsure about it.

Comment: You will output float values in any case (use the `softmax` activation function for your output layer. Picking the top 350 seems like the most straightforward way to go